# Unable to rotate continuous joint using Joint state publisher gui, Two wheeled self balancing robot

Tags: ros, rviz, mobile-robot

I am working on two wheeled self balancing robot on ROS1.
It has three parts, left_wheel, right_wheel, body.
It is a mobile robot. It has two continuous joints at two wheels.
.
I am trying to rotate wheels in RViz using Joint state publisher gui. As my robot is mobile robot, I think there should not be any fixed frame in RViz.
.
Though model is loaded in RViz, controlling the gui slider does not make any difference on the wheels or body.
.
Is it really possible to use Joint state publisher gui to visualize motion in case of mobile robots? If so, am I missing any point?

If you need any file or anything to comment on any improvement please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your ROS distribution.

For ROS 2: In principle this should work.

have a look at the [diffbot example of ros2_control](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_2/doc/userdoc.html), I just found a tiny bug: Use `ros2 launch ros2_control_demo_example_2 view_robot.launch.py` from [this PR](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/pull/377).

Comment: I am using ROS1. When I import in Gazebo and simulate, the self balancing robot falls down as expected and wheel movement is visible.